# The box doesn't work (html/css)

Tags: html, css, block

So can anyone tell what's wrong with my code? So I'm trying to add a blue dashed 'block', but somewhy it doesn't get displayed (it seems like the font gets changed, but the box still doesn't appear). I had an similar problem before, but I don't know what's wrong this time. Am I missing a semicolon somewhere or just wrote something wrong?

When I launch the code in JSFiddle, it seems to work fine, but when I'm opening the SAME code with the .html file, everything still seems not to work (pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb0ty.png). I'm Anyone got ideas why (the css file is in right location)?

https://jsfiddle.net/j31dgz70/1/

```css
#info {
  color: blue;
  background: silver;
}

.welcome {
  color: purple;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px silver;
}

#tab {
  background-color: blue;
}

code {
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #7FECFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  border: 1px dashed #540CE8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <p id="tab"><b>About page</b>

  </p>
  <article>
    <code class="box">
      Contact: <a href="mailto:exmaple@example.com">Email me</a>
    </code>

    <a href="index.html"><br>Return to homepage.</a>

  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: I converted your code into a live example and it worked. The problem can't have been exposed by the code you shared.

Comment: Comic sans might be an issue. ;) You can use a css validator to check your code for errors: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: You have set 40px for the width of 'code' but the text is longer than 40px

Answer (score 2):

It's the `<br/>` that is causing the problem.

It forces a line break but the height restricts what is visible.

Remove the break tag. If you want spacing, use margins or padding...that's what they are for.

```css
    code {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
      display: inline-block height: 20px;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 4px;
      background-color: #7FECFF;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .box {
      border: 1px dashed #540CE8;
    }
```

```html
<code class="box">
Contact: <a href="mailto:exmaple@example.com">Email me</a>
</code>

<code class="box">
    Contact: <a href="mailto:exmaple@example.com">Email me<br/></a>
</code>
```

Alternate Options if you wanted the 'box' to have two lines

Option 1: Retain the break tag but move it. (Not optimal but ok)

```css
    code {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 4px;
      background-color: #7FECFF;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .box {
      border: 1px dashed #540CE8;
    }
```

```html
<code class="box">
    Contact: <br/><a href="mailto:exmaple@example.com">Email me</a>
</code>
```

Option 2: Make the link a block

```css
    code {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 4px;
      background-color: #7FECFF;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .box {
      border: 1px dashed #540CE8;
    }
    .box a {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<code class="box">
    Contact: <a href="mailto:exmaple@example.com">Email me</a>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add width: 160px; for responsive use width: 40% or any value according to screen

```
.box {
    width: 160px;
border: 1px dashed #540CE8;
}
```

Here is link [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r3L7k776/)

Comment: How about remove the width paramater altogether and remove display:block also?

Answer (score 0):

The bordered box is showing fine here, however everything seems broken as its trying to fit inside 'code' which is only 40px wide.

If you remove the width it seems to render fine.

```
code {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #7FECFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/tomdurkin/pen/vOeLVb

Answer (score 0):

This is how it comes out to me on fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jimmynewbs/j31dgz70/

```
see fiddle
```

The code you have specified as 40px wide, so the text is too big for that section.

I would suggest making the width larger, or removing the width and floating the element so that it will take the width of it's content...